# Setting High Score - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

So I have my score label working perfectly. Destroy monsters and boom, you get points. But, I'm having a little trouble implementing a best score label.

I know this is a lot of code posted. But that's only so you can get an idea of what my game is exactly doing.

Here is what I have working to show points:

HudNode.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface HudNode : SKNode

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger lives;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger score;

+ (instancetype) hudAtPosition:(CGPoint)poistion inFrame:(CGRect)frame;

- (void) addPoints:(NSInteger)points;
- (BOOL) loseLife;
@end
```

HudNode.m

```
#import "HudNode.h"
#import "Utill.h"

@implementation HudNode

+ (instancetype) hudAtPosition:(CGPoint)poistion inFrame:(CGRect)frame {
HudNode *hud = [self node];
hud.position = poistion;
hud.zPosition = 10;
hud.name = @"HUD";

SKLabelNode *scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Futura-CondensedExtraBold"];
scoreLabel.name = @"Score";
scoreLabel.text = @"0";
scoreLabel.fontSize = 24;
scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width-55, -20);
[hud addChild:scoreLabel];


- (void) addPoints:(NSInteger)points {
self.score += points;
SKLabelNode *scoreLabel = (SKLabelNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"Score"];
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)self.score];
}
```

So all that is working fine to show a display of points earned through game play. Now, what I tried to do to add a best score is the following.

HudMode.h

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger bestScore;

- (void) setHighScore:(NSInteger)highScore;
```

Then in HudNode.m I tried adding the following:

```
SKLabelNode *bestScoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Futura-CondensedExtraBold"];
bestScoreLabel.name = @"BestScore";
bestScoreLabel.text = @"0";
bestScoreLabel.fontSize = 24;
bestScoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;
bestScoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width-100, -20);
[hud addChild:bestScoreLabel];

- (void) setBestScore:(NSInteger)bestScore {
self.score >= bestScore;
SKLabelNode *bestScoreLabel = (SKLabelNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"BestScore"];
bestScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",()self.bestScore];
}
```

I even got it to the point where both label were updating at the same time but the best score was not saving at all.

Comment: The best score wasn't saving *where*?

Comment: Where are you saving the score? Are you using NSUserDefaults or something?

Answer (score 0):

`self.score >= bestScore` is just an expression and isn't assigning a value to your `score` variable.

I would imagine you'd have something like :

```
if (score > bestScore)
{
    bestScore = score
}
```

However, your code is a bit confusing. If you have already determined that you have a new best score before you call that method, you would have something like :

```
bestScore = score;
```

You also have `setHighScore` defined as a method in your .h file, yet in your implementation you have `setBestScore`

This doesn't feel much like a question/answer worthwhile of keeping around, as it's more like "debug my code".

Answer (score 0):

Hi @MyPalVikram i would recommend you to start with NSUserDefaults --> stored locally (before  exploring how to save scores to game center). To make things simple for you, I've provided the code in which i use to store the high score for my game.

```
// Store user profile to NSUserDefaults
- (void)saveUserProfile{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    double bestBossScore = [userDefaults doubleForKey:@"bestBossScore"]; // Get bestHighScore

    collectedStars = self.score;
    [userDefaults setDouble:collectedStars forKey:@"collectedStars"]; // Set collected Stars

    // Compare if the current score is more than the previous high score
    if (self.score > bestBossScore) {
         [userDefaults setDouble:self.score forKey:@"bestBossScore"]; // Set Highscores
    }
    [userDefaults synchronize]; // Remember to include this
}
```

Run the [self saveUserProfile] when the game ends or when the user quits the game(if that's the behaviour you want)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I will most def test it out!

Answer (score -1):

```
//int = highscore     
//int = _score

 highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] 
    intValue ];

        highScoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 20, 50, 30)];

        highScoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:25];

        highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)highScore];

        highScoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.view addSubview:highScoreLabel];

        if (_score > highScore) {
            highScore = _score;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_score];
        }
```